# Yii2 MaskedInput / MaskedMoney for Integer Only money storage

Tags: regex, yii2, masking

In my database I store money as an integer, similar to Stripe.  For instance 12.99 is stored as 1299.  Basically taking the number and dividing by 100.

I'm trying to incorporate this with Yii2 activeForm, specifically using either the MaskInput or MaskMoney widgets.  However, I cannot figure out how to configure either widget so that when the value is "1299" it displays as "12.99".  So if a person types in "1200" it displays as "12.00".

This is for a simple frontend solution and not backend so I'm not looking for Yii scenarios or behaviors in this question.

Comment: As I was telling you yesterday, you could simply use a getter/setter...

Comment: First off this is a completely different solution and approach.  It is not the same question.  Second off I can't just simply use a getter and setter.  This has to happen after the object is already instantiated. I can't use scenarios because I'm pulling the object from an array of objects in a hasMany call.  And it has to work with the activeForm, and it has to only do this in a certain situation.  I don't want this happening every time I get or set the object.  So similar to yesterday your answer is not right.

Comment: I dont see the problem, using getter/setter will work... You should delete this question and add more details in your first one.

Comment: I have updated my other question as your current request applies to that one.  If you believe you can use a getter / setter to populate the active form field, limited to only this situation, I would like to see your solution.

Comment: Of course you can, you just have to replace `price` with `realPrice`

Comment: Ah.  I stand corrected.  I did not realize you can reference another getter and setter as a model attribute in the form.  Cool trick. Thank you sir.  That sufficiently answers my original question and solves my problem but doesn't really address the question here with MaskInput / Money.  I'm still curious how I could get this to work as well.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but this is the closest I've ever got to what you want.

```
<?php echo \yii\widgets\MaskedInput::widget([
    'name' => 'masked-input',
    'clientOptions' => [
        'alias' => 'decimal',
        'digits' => 2,
        'digitsOptional' => false,
        'radixPoint' => '.',
        'groupSeparator' => ',',
        'autoGroup' => true,
        'removeMaskOnSubmit' => true,
    ],
]); ?>
```

The behaviour of the decimal part is what bothers me, but it works as intended.

Comment: This did not work for me.  The value "1927" which I would like to appear as "19.27" is actually appearing as "1,927." with these parameters.